# Authenticate rails_admin with admin attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I want to be able to just let the users that have an **admin attribute set to true** to access rails_admin.  So, if a user has the is_admin attribute to true, they can access the rails_admin interface.

I have checked their documentation and all I can find about authentication is here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authentication

Please, could you help me to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Authorization

```
config.authorize_with do
  redirect_to main_app.root_path unless current_user.is_admin?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation already explains, what you have to do:

In your rails_admin.rb initializer:

```
config.authenticate_with do
  warden.authenticate! :scope => :admin
end
config.current_user_method { current_admin } # hook to your 'current_user' method
```

And in your User Model you generate the current_admin method:

```
def current_admin
  current_user && current_user.is_admin
end
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Mattherick what does this warden.authenticate! :scope => :admin mean?

Comment: maybe this answer your question: https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki/Scopes. you can configure your rails_admin to use warden authentication.